# Result of bash expression fails to be interpreted as a string

Tags: linux, bash, curl

Trying to download latest SBT version from GitHub:

`version="$(curl -vsLk https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/latest 2>&1 | grep "< Location" | rev | cut -d'/' -f1 | rev)"`

*`version` is set to `v1.1.0-RC2`*

Then attempting to download the .tar.gz package:

`curl -fsSLk "https://github.com/sbt/sbt/archive/${version}.tar.gz" | tar xvfz - -C /home/myuser`

However, instead of the correct URL:

`https://github.com/sbt/sbt/archive/v1.1.0-RC2.tar.gz`

Somehow the version string is interpreted as a command(?!), resulting in:

`.tar.gzttps://github.com/sbt/sbt/archive/v1.1.0-RC2`

When I manually set `version="v1.1.0-RC2"`, this doesn't happen.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's absolutely part of the string -- it's just a string that contains a sequence that sends the cursor back to the front of the line, so when it's printed, it *looks* like it's overwriting the command. Doesn't mean anything like that is actually happening.

Comment: Thank you @BenjaminW.! adding a ` | sed 's/\r//g' ` at the end fixed it.

Comment: BTW, this is literally the very first thing in the "before asking about problematic code" section in the [`bash` tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `-I` flag in `curl` command and a **much simpler** pipeline to grab version number like this:

```
curl -sILk https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/latest |
awk -F '[/ ]+' '$1 == "Location:"{sub(/\r$/, ""); print $NF}'

v1.1.0-RC2
```

Also note use of `sub` function to strip off `\r` from end of line of `curl` output.

**Your script:**

```
version=$(curl -sILk https://github.com/sbt/sbt/releases/latest | awk -F '[/ ]+' '$1 == "Location:"{sub(/\r$/, ""); print $NF}')

curl -fsSLk "https://github.com/sbt/sbt/archive/${version}.tar.gz" | tar xvfz - -C /home/myuser
```